# Ms Access 2013 Criteria that add 14 days

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two entities for a library, one is "Book Date Borrowed" and the other is "Book Due For Return Date". I want the date of return to be 14 days after the book date borrowed. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: @whoever downvoted this question, please add a comment explaining your reason.  This user is new and probably not psychic.

Comment: @PowerUser - You both need to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dateadd("d",14,mydatevariable)
```

Comment: This is almost certainly incorrect. The first argument needs to be a string and the second argument should be a number.

Comment: Correct, it should be `DateAdd("d",14,mydatevariable)`. You can use single quotes instead of double if using it inside an SQL query and not VBA.

Comment: You are both correct.  I updated my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here.  You can use the `DateAdd` function, which I would recommend or you can use the addition operator.

Recommended:

```
Dim datIssued As Date
Dim datDue As Date

datIssued = Now()

'calculate due date
datDue = DateAdd("d", 14, datIssued)

'update record
Me.FieldName = datDue
```

or the alternative:

```
Dim datIssued As Date
Dim datDue As Date

datIssued = Now()

'calculate due date
datDue = datIssued + 14
```